# How can I best _select_ which of the internal parameters to operate on?

Tags: c++, function

This is a simple question.  I have a class CubeMap.  Inside the CubeMap class is a `vector<ColorValue>`, that contains the color values for each of the 6 faces of the cubemap.

```
class CubeMap
{
    vector<ColorValue> colorValues, rotatedColorValues ;
    void save( char* filename ) ;
} ;
```

The cubemap can be rotated as the program runs.  If it is rotated, then rotatedColorValues contains the rotated version and colorValues always contains the original version.

CubeMap has a member function `save( char* filename );`  The original cubemap is *always* stored in colorValues, and a "rotated" version of the cubemap MAY OR MAY NOT be stored in rotatedColorValues.

Now the save routine will either save colorValues **or** rotatedColorValues.  I have a few options.

How can I best *select* which of the internal parameters to operate on?

Change the signature of `CubeMap::save` to:

```
// 1. use the name:
void saveRotatedVersion( char* filename ) ;
void saveOriginal( char* filename ) ;

// 2. OR use a parameter:
void save( char* filename, bool rotatedVersion ) ;

// 3. OR turn it into a static function and require the object
// being saved to be included
static void save( char* filename, const vector<ColorValue> &toSave ) ;

// 4. OR use an enum
enum CubeMapObject { Original, Rotated } ;
static void save( char* filename, CubeMapObject objectToSave ) ;
```

### edit:

a 5. I could also set an internal state parameter, as a selector of sorts

```
class CubeMap
{
    vector<ColorValue> colorValues, rotatedColorValues, *currentSource ;
    // save uses currentSource, whatever that points to
    void save( char* filename ) ;
} ;
```

Which of these is the best option, and why?

Comment: You should use `const char*` instead of `char*`

Comment: No, _you_ should use `const char*`.  But really, thanks for the comment, and I probably would use `const char *` and label the `save` function `const` as well,

Answer (score 2):

I would go with number 1 or number 4. Number 2 loses to number 4 in readability, and is not as self-explanatory as number 4, while number 3 reveals too much implementation.

Number three is a good thing to have as a *private* method hiding implementation details of your saving process.

P.S. Number 4 would be more appropriate if you expect to add other `CubeMapObject` values, say, `RotatedLeft` and `RotatedRight`.

Comment: I would still use #3 for an internal implementation detail.  Perhaps that implementation can even be used for other color saving, not just cube maps.  And #4 could simply delegate to #3, passing the appropriate version.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using my final edit:

```
class CubeMap
{
    vector<ColorValue> colorValues, rotatedColorValues, *currentSource ;

    // save uses currentSource, whatever that points to
    void save( char* filename ) ;

    void setSource( vector<ColorValue> *newSource ) ;
    void revertToPreviousSource() ; // "pop"
} ;
```

This has the advantage of making it so the interface functions simply named.  In addition, all cCubeMap functions now use the `currentSource` pointer, so everything becomes cleaner.